# MSTest fails to load dll from network share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, mstest, network-share, fileshare

I am running MSTest (on a Microsoft Azure VM) to test a DLL which is in a network file share (linked to Azure File Storage).

I get this error -

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///P:\test\bin\mydll.dll' or one
>   of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1:

xcopy the folder containing the dll and its dependencies from the network share to a local disk and run it from there.

### Solution 2:

This solution is preferable because it saves the copy step.

Find the folder that contains MSTest.exe. In my case here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

Open `MSTest.exe.config` (it should already exist) and add the following line under`<runtime>` :

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
```

in context:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   ...
```

From: [MSDN: <loadFromRemoteSources> element.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(v=vs.110).aspx)

Confusingly, it says:

> In the .NET Framework 4.5, assemblies on local network shares are run
>   as full trust by default; you do not have to enable the
>   <loadFromRemoteSources> element.

I am targeting .NET 4.5, but I got the error until I enabled loadFromRemoteSources.